# Problems after using external bluetooth sound device in 17.04

Tags: sound, 17.04, headphones, bluetooth-speaker

I am using Ubuntu 17.04. After using an external sound device via bluetooth (which worked well) my sound settings seem broken:

1. The built-in speakers of my computer (HP Spectre) don't output any sound.
2. Sound is working propperly when headphones are plugged in.
3. In Hardware->Sound->Output "Play sound throuh" is set to "Speakers. Built in Audio" and the output volume is set to 100%
4. This behaviour is stable after turning the computer off and on again and against all changes I can do in the Ubuntu sound settings.
5. This behaviour is stable against turning off bluetooth via `sudo service bluetooth stop`
6. Checking to attach all available profiles to the speakers in pavucontrol->configuration does not lead to any effect.
7. In alsamixer, the Speakers are shown as enabled. Mute-Unmuting them does not lead to any effect.
8. `amixer contents` gives the following result:

   ```
   numid=19,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=3 Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=25,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=7 Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=31,iface=CARD,name='HDMI/DP,pcm=8 Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=15,iface=CARD,name='Headphone Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=14,iface=CARD,name='Internal Mic Phantom Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=on
   numid=13,iface=CARD,name='Mic Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=16,iface=CARD,name='Speaker Phantom Jack'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=r-------,values=1   : values=on
   numid=12,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Switch'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1   : values=on 
   numid=11,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'   ; ,
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=1,min=0,max=87,step=0   : values=67    
                   | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
   numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Switch'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2   : values=off,off
   numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Headphone Playback Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=87,step=0   : values=0,0   
                   | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
   numid=40,iface=MIXER,name='PCM Playback Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---RW-,values=2,min=0,max=255,step=0   : values=255,255   
                   | dBscale-min=-51.00dB,step=0.20dB,mute=0
   numid=9,iface=MIXER,name='Mic Boost Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0   : values=0,0   
                   | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
   numid=8,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2   : values=on,on
   numid=7,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=63,step=0   : values=38,38   
                   | dBscale-min=-17.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
   numid=5,iface=MIXER,name='Loopback Mixing'   ;
           type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2   ; Item #0 'Disabled'   ; Item #1 'Enabled'   : values=0 
   numid=20,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask'   ;
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=26,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=1   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=32,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Con Mask',index=2   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0xff AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask'   ;
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=27,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=1   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=33,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Pro Mask',index=2   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=r-------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x0f AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default'   ;
           type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=28,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=1   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=34,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Default',index=2   ; 
           type=IEC958,access=rw------,values=1   : values=[AES0=0x04 AES1=0x00 AES2=0x00 AES3=0x00] 
   numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1   : values=off
   numid=29,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=1   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1   : values=on
   numid=35,iface=MIXER,name='IEC958 Playback Switch',index=2   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=1   : values=on
   numid=6,iface=MIXER,name='Auto-Mute Mode'   ;
           type=ENUMERATED,access=rw------,values=1,items=2   ; Item #0 'Disabled'   ; Item #1 'Enabled'   : values=1 
   numid=10,iface=MIXER,name='Internal Mic Boost Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=3,step=0   : values=0,0   
                   | dBscale-min=0.00dB,step=10.00dB,mute=0
   numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Switch'   ;
           type=BOOLEAN,access=rw------,values=2   : values=on,on
   numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Speaker Playback Volume'   ;
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=2,min=0,max=87,step=0   : values=87,87   
                   | dBscale-min=-65.25dB,step=0.75dB,mute=0
   numid=18,iface=PCM,name='Capture Channel Map'   ; 
           type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0   : values=0,0   
                   | container
                   | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
   numid=17,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map'   ; 
           type=INTEGER,access=r----R--,values=2,min=0,max=36,step=0   : values=0,0        
                   | container
                   | chmap-fixed=FL,FR
   numid=24,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=3   ;
           type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0   : values=
   numid=37,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=3   ; 
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0   : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
                   | container
                   | chmap-variable=FL,FR
   numid=30,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=7   ;
           type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0   : values=
   numid=38,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=7   ; 
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0   : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
                   | container
                   | chmap-variable=FL,FR
   numid=36,iface=PCM,name='ELD',device=8   ; 
           type=BYTES,access=r--v----,values=0   : values=
   numid=39,iface=PCM,name='Playback Channel Map',device=8   ; 
           type=INTEGER,access=rw---R--,values=8,min=0,max=36,step=0   : values=0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0   
                   | container
                   | chmap-variable=FL,FR
   ```

Is this a bug? If yes, where can I report it? How can I fix it?

Comment: Install pavucontrol and verify which audio devices are attached to your apps. Probably bluetooth usage leads to a "fictional output" after its broken.

Comment: I installed pavucontrol now. But I don't understand the rest of your comment. I don't see any options in pavucontrol coming close to what you mention.

Comment: Start by going to your system settings and selecting “Sound” under “Hardware”.  Click on the “Output” tab and make sure it’s set to “Speakers – Built-in Audio” and that the output volume is turned up.

Comment: @bashBedlam: I already did that, sorry not to mention it.

Comment: Open pavucontrol, go to Settings tab and see which profile is attached to your sound device. Try change while you app is executing sound.

Comment: Additionally, you can see in alsamixer (at terminal session) if your output are all enabled. type M to moute-unmute and up-down to change level.

Comment: With "Settings" you mean "Configuration"? I tried all profiles there, no one made the sound hearable.

Comment: In alsamixer, the Speakers are enabled. Mute-Unmuting them does not lead to any effect.

Comment: Did you chose your audio device? Press <F6> to see. Post the output of '*amixer contents*' here, please.

Comment: @Redbob Ich chose "Speaker". I edited my question and added the output of *amixer contents*

Comment: Maybe I should mention that Ubuntu is installed alongside Windows 10 on my computer. In Windows, the speakers are working propperly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64823/discussion-between-redbob-and-jonathan-scholbach).